# await in sychronous function?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

yeah, I didn't find any coverage of this topic, so I thought I'd give it a shot here. I'm trying to add a loading animation within an existing function, which returns a list of strings. My code looks like this:

```
IoC.Get<IEventAggregator>()
         .PublishOnUIThread(new ShowWaitingAnimationArgs
         {
             DisplayMessage = "Updating database file...",
             ShowWaitingAnimation = true
         });
     Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     {
         ResultList = update.HandledDifferences(testContext, realContext, imo);
         IoC.Get<IEventAggregator>()
             .PublishOnUIThread(new ShowWaitingAnimationArgs {ShowWaitingAnimation = false});
     });
     return ResultList;
```

the IoC[...] calls are basically just messages sent to a framework, which enable and then disable the loading animation. The actual work is done in update.HandledDifferences function, which basically updates my database file and returns a list of possible error occurences.
So right now I want to calculate HandledDifferences and show the loading animation while it's calculated (so neither UI thread nor this one get blocked), and after it's done, I want to return the result - pretty much what's written in that code. 
However, since it's asynchronous, it doesnt even wait for my ResultList to be calculated, it just returns the value which is in there at the time.

I already tried calling the return value of the task and waiting for the task, where both options ended up blocking the UI thread (Task.wait sometimes even would block the task itself, so it never got completed and I never got past that line).

I'm pretty much out of ideas now. I just want to await the task to be completed, but I can't do that because its not a asynchronous method and it can't be made into one (it has to implement an interface). Any ideas how to do that? Admittedly, I'm not really experiences with asynchronous programming, but I couldnt find anything like that anywhere.

Comment: If you ***really*** can't change your method signature, your options are limited, as your method is by design synchronous.  Without having more details about your context, it's hard to recommend better alternatives.  But, to me, it sounds like your method shouldn't be doing any UI work at all.  It sounds like it's the caller's responsibility to do that.  But you would have to provide more details about the calling class/method as well to see if that's possible.

Comment: this function is in the Business Logic Layer, it gets called by the view model which handles Login Requests. This method basically checks if the password is correct, if the database is there, if it's a current version, updates if necessary and then displays pending differences in the database schema. this work really doesn't sound to me as if it should be done asynchronously

Comment: @DevilSuichiro: Anything I/O-based should be asynchronous. Database calls are I/O-based. Sounds to me like it's asynchronous. Why should it *not* be done asynchronously?

Comment: of course, the database related stuff (this function), which just can't be done asynchronously because of interface issues. I was talking about the viewmodel, which has to be done synchronously, because each step is dependant on the ones before. So, if I understand you correctly, you suggest I should just outsource the HandledDifferences() call+IO to another asynchronous function? to be clear, because I can't really try it out right now... wouldn't a call to WhatEverTheHellIWouldCallThatFunction().Result block the UI thread?

Answer (score 0):

By calling Wait() or Result on an Task on the UI thread will deadlock the UI thread if you are using async-await.

You haven't post the signature of the method that code belongs to or the calling code, but I think this would work:

```
async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    IoC.Get<IEventAggregator>()
         .PublishOnUIThread(new ShowWaitingAnimationArgs
         {
             DisplayMessage = "Updating database file...",
             ShowWaitingAnimation = true
         });

    var resultList = await Task.Run(
        () => update.HandledDifferences(testContext, realContext, imo));

    IoC.Get<IEventAggregator>()
        .PublishOnUIThread(new ShowWaitingAnimationArgs {ShowWaitingAnimation = false});

    return ResultList;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, OP did specify that his method's signature could not be changed due to having to implement an interface.  So based on his existing code, it doesn't look like he can change his method to return a `Task<T>`. That's the point of his question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AsyncBridge](https://github.com/tejacques/AsyncBridge) which will allow you to execute asynchronous methods without blocking the UI thread.

```
IoC.Get<IEventAggregator>()
         .PublishOnUIThread(new ShowWaitingAnimationArgs
         {
             DisplayMessage = "Updating database file...",
             ShowWaitingAnimation = true
         });

    using (var A = AsyncHelper.Wait)
    {
        A.Run(Task.Run( () => update.HandledDifferences(testContext, realContext, imo)), res => ResultList = res);
    }

    IoC.Get<IEventAggregator>()
             .PublishOnUIThread(new ShowWaitingAnimationArgs {ShowWaitingAnimation = false});

     return ResultList;
```